# Decimal keycode in locale region

Tags: c#

If I use something like the following

```
bool isKeyDecimal = e.KeyCode == Keys.Decimal;
```

Does `Keys.Decimal` automatically use the localized regional character for a decimal which could be either a `.` or a `,` depending on the region or does it always mean `.`

I have textboxes that use float values and I want to make sure that I handle regional differences in the floating point decimal character.

Comment: Why not try it and see?

Comment: `Keys.Decimal` is the virtual key code for the decimal key on the keyboard, not for the decimal symbol.  It can be mapped to the appropriate character based on the users culture.